# Python: Convert format string to regular expression

Tags: python, regex, formatting

The users of my app can configure the layout of certain files via a format string.

For example, the config value the user specifies might be:

```
layout = '%(group)s/foo-%(locale)s/file.txt'
```

I now need to find all such files that already exist. This seems easy enough using the **glob** module:

```
glob_pattern = layout % {'group': '*', 'locale': '*'}
glob.glob(glob_pattern)
```

However, now comes the hard part: Given the list of glob results, I need to get all those filename-parts that matched a given placeholder, for example all the different "locale" values.

I thought I would generate a regular expression for the format string that I could then match against the list of glob results (or then possibly skipping glob and doing all the matching myself).

But I can't find a nice way to create the regex with both the proper group captures, and escaping the rest of the input.

For example, this might give me a regex that matches the locales:

```
regex = layout % {'group': '.*', 'locale': (.*)}
```

But to be sure the regex is valid, I need to pass it through re.escape(), which then also escapes the regex syntax I have just inserted. Calling re.escape() first ruins the format string.

I know there's fnmatch.translate(), which would even give me a regex - but not one that returns the proper groups.

Is there a good way to do this, without a hack like replacing the placeholders with a regex-safe unique value etc.?

Is there possibly some way (a third party library perhaps?) that allows dissecting a format string in a more flexible way, for example splitting the string at the placeholder locations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using named placeholders, I'd use named groups. This seems to work:

```
import re
UNIQ='_UNIQUE_STRING_'
class MarkPlaceholders(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return UNIQ+('(?P<%s>.*?)'%key)+UNIQ

def format_to_re(format):
    parts = (format % MarkPlaceholders()).split(UNIQ)
    for i in range(0, len(parts), 2):
        parts[i] = re.escape(parts[i])
    return ''.join(parts)
```

and then to test:

```
>>> layout = '%(group)s/foo-%(locale)s/file.txt'
>>> print format_to_re(layout)
(?P<group>.*?)\/foo\-(?P<locale>.*?)\/file\.txt
>>> pattern = re.compile(format_to_re(layout))
>>> print pattern.match('something/foo-en-gb/file.txt').groupdict()
{'locale': 'en-gb', 'group': 'something'}
```

Comment: I had hoped to find a way other than using a unique identifier, but this is an interesting spin on that approach. In particular, I like that I'll only need a single unique separator, rather than one for every field that needs to match a different regular expression.

Comment: If the unique separator worries you too much you could always include a number in it and increment the number until you get something that isn't in the string.

Comment: ok, this works for strings, would it be possible to make this work for more constructs?
like parsing "node%(id)03d" to "node(?P<id>\d\d\d)"

Answer (score 1):

You can try this; it works around your escaping problems.

```
unique = '_UNIQUE_STRING_'
assert unique not in layout
regexp = re.escape(layout % {'group': unique, 'locale': unique}).replace(unique, '(.*)')
```